# Send sms - body not transmitted in Lollipop

Tags: java, android, sms, android-5.0-lollipop

The following lines should open the sms dialog in order to send a sms.
On Api 19, the body is transmitted to the dialog, but on Lollipop, it remains blank.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", bodySms); 
context.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Help of CommonsWare, this did the trick :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, bodySms); 
context.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

> The following lines should open the sms dialog in order to send a sms.

Not necessarily. What you are actually asking Android to do is to find an activity that handles `ACTION_VIEW` on a MIME type of `vnd.android-dir/mms-sms`. You are not asking to send an SMS.

Moreover, if you read [the documentation for `ACTION_VIEW`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW), you will not find a mention of an `sms_body` extra.

If you want to send an SMS, [use `ACTION_SEND`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) with `EXTRA_TEXT` or [perhaps `sms_body`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Messaging).

Comment: With ACTION_SEND, the sms activity isn't proposed, only gmail and 3 or 4 other ones. But with ACTION_VIEW and the EXTRA_TEXT, it works. Thanks for the advices.